# What's the matrix representation of Slave-Boson operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, many-body, lattice-model, bose-hubbard-model

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
I think I'm not understanding the construction of the slave-particle operators.

In the Bose-Hubbard model, the slave-boson approach attempts to alter the representation of filling states on the lattice, such that the physical occupation of a site is depicted by the occupation of fictitious bosons
$$\ket{n}_i \rightarrow \ket{n^0,n^1,...,n^{n_{max}-1},n^{n_{max}}}$$
created from the vacuum through $n_{max}+1$ operators $\beta_n^\dagger$, operating as
\begin{equation}
    \beta_{n,i}^\dagger \ket{vac}_i=\ket{n}_i
\end{equation}
that means
\begin{align*}
&\ket{0} \rightarrow \ket{1,0,0,0,0}                                     \\
&\ket{1} \rightarrow \ket{0,1,0,0,0}                                     \\
&\ket{2} \rightarrow \ket{0,0,1,0,0} ,\hspace{0.5cm} \ket{0,2,0,0,0}                   \\
&\ket{3} \rightarrow \ket{0,0,0,1,0} ,\hspace{0.5cm} \ket{0,3,0,0,0} ,\hspace{0.5cm} \ket{0,1,1,0,0} , \\
&\ket{4} \rightarrow \ket{0,0,0,0,1} ,\hspace{0.5cm} \ket{0,4,0,0,0} ,\hspace{0.5cm} \ket{0,1,0,1,0} ,\hspace{0.5cm} \ket{0,2,1,0,0} ,\hspace{0.5cm} \ket{0,0,2,0,0}
\end{align*}
As some states have multiple representations, the following constraint is introduced
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{n_{max}=0}^{n_{max}+1} \beta_{n_i}^\dagger\beta_{n,i}=1
\end{equation}
giving a representation
\begin{equation}
    \beta_{n}^{\dagger}=\underbrace{\dots \otimes \mathbb{I}_{n-1} \otimes 
     \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}_n 
     \otimes \mathbb{I} _{n+1} \otimes \dots}_{n_{max}+1}
\end{equation}

Reconstructing the original physical boson operator as
\begin{equation}
    b_i=\sum_{n=0}^{n_{max}} \sqrt{n+1}\beta_{i,n}^\dagger\beta_{i,n+1}
\end{equation}

In the complete representation, performing the kronecker products, $dim (\beta_n^{\dagger})=2^{n_{max}+1}$. For the case $n_{max}=2$ the matrices look like
\begin{equation}
\beta_0^{\dagger}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\beta_1^{\dagger}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\beta_2^{\dagger}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation}

Is this correct? am I not understanding something about the slave-particle theory? how can I represent these operators matricially?